# C wiringPi wait until function is completed

Tags: c, wiringpi

I'm not a **C** developer but i need to write simple program and i have problems with delay. Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <softPwm.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int val = 10;
  if (argc > 1) {
    val = atoi(argv[1]);
  }
  wiringPiSetup ()  ;

  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  softPwmCreate (1, 0, 100) ;
  printf ("Soft Pwm created: %s!\n", argv[1]) ;

  softPwmWrite (1, val) ;

  delay (200);

  return 0;
}
```

And it works pretty well until i delete row with **delay (200)**. How can i wait until function softPwmWrite complete without **delay()** before program has done?
Im' using **Linux** and **wiringPi** library. Thanks.

Comment: If you have any side-effects of `softPwmWrite ()`, you can check that in a loop before finishing, but that's pretty course way, anyway.

Comment: I think that's not a question about language, but about a particular library, `softPwm`, I thinik.

Comment: `delay` is not a standard C library, and C is not the same as C++ (so choose one!). You probably are using some operating system, name it!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, yeah, sorry, just edited my question. When i said i'm not a C/C++ developer i meant i've never write code for such level.

Comment: @Petr, yes. You are right. Sorry, i just need to solve this problem and i don't have enough reputation to put wiringPi in the tag section.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? Pls leave some comments. I've noticed i'm not C/C++ developer and never code on such level before. What's wrong?

Comment: Probably people didn't get that you couldn't create the missing tags.

Answer (score 1):

Include `pthread.h` and call `pthread_exit`:

```
#include <pthread.h>

....

softPwmWrite (1, val) ;
pthread_exit(0);
}
```

When the `softPwmWrite` returns, it'll exit the program. softPwmWrite uses threads and you just need ensure your program doesn't die before the threads complete. When all threads complete, the process will exit at the end.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but i need to exit the program after function is completed

Comment: @Footniko I hope my edit makes it clear. Why do you need to exit yourself?